# Strange missing lines when reading file with readline.createInterface()

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

```js
const readline = require('readline')
const fs = require('fs/promises');

(async function() {

  await fs.writeFile('/tmp/input.txt', [...Array(100000).keys()].join('\n'))
  await fs.writeFile('/tmp/other.txt', 'test'.repeat(1000))

  const fileStream = require('fs').createReadStream('/tmp/input.txt')

  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fileStream,
    crlfDelay: Infinity
  });

  await fs.readFile('/tmp/other.txt', 'utf-8')

  let i = 0
  for await (const num of rl) {
    i++
  }
  console.log(i)

})();
```

If I run the above script I expect `100000` as an output. Instead I get:

```
$ node wtf.js
65381
$ node wtf.js
76303
$ node wtf.js
65381
$ node wtf.js
76303
$ node wtf.js
65381
```

However if I remove the `await fs.readFile(...)` line I always get the correct answer `100000`. What could explain that behavior?

Node version is 18.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spotted the answer in the docs after posting this:

> readline.createInterface() will start to consume the input stream once invoked. Having asynchronous operations between interface creation and asynchronous iteration may result in missed lines.

Comment: **Blech** (the API, not the answer). That's stinky enough that I'd have a wrapper function for it: `function readlineAsync(options) { const rl = readline.createInterface(options); return rl[Symbol.asyncIterator](); }` Drop that in instead of `readline.createInterface` and your code works as expected.